# static methods, return results and print results out

Tags: java

I am working on some online training for java and having difficulty with this concept.

This is what I'm trying to do.  I'm close but not sure what I'm missing.

Create a `MetricConverter` class with the following methods (each method receives a metric value and returns the corresponding standard value):

- kgToLbs(kg:double):double (+ means public; requires a double parameter; returns a double value)
- kmToMiles(km:double):double

Create a `MetricConverterTest` application that runs from the following menu:

KG to lbs
KM to miles

So I'm close but The `MetricConverter` class should only contain four static methods - nothing else.

I can figure out the static methods and returns...but not how to display that returned result back.  What am I missing?

The `MetricConverterTest` class should have a main method that displays the menu.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MetricConverter {
    private static Scanner keyBd = new Scanner(System.in);

    //method if 1 is selected
    public static double menuOption1() {
        double kg = keyBd.nextDouble();
        double lbs = 2.20462*kg;
        return lbs;
    }

    //method if 2 is selected
    public static double menuOption2() {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of kilometers you wish to convert: ");
        double km = keyBd.nextDouble();
        double miles = 0.621371 *km;
        return miles;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char selection;
        do {
            //displays the menu    
            System.out.println("\n\nMainMenu");  
            System.out.println("1. Convert KG to lbs");
            System.out.println("2. Convert kilometers to miles");
            System.out.println("3. Quit");
            System.out.println("Selection: ");

            //get a menu selection
            selection = keyBd.next().charAt(0);

            switch(selection) {
                case '1': menuOption1(); break;
                case '2': menuOption2(); break;
                case '3': break;
                default: System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
            }//end switch
        } while(selection != '3');
    }//end main()
}
```

Comment: what is happening ? what error ?

Comment: Read the assignment. It asks you to create a MetricConverter class with **two** methods named kgToLbs and kmToMiles. Your class has 3 methods, named menuOption1, menuOption2, and main. You're not respecting any of the instructions in the assignment.

Comment: And you print it out the same way you print anything else out: set it to a variable (which you already know how to do) and print it (which you already know how to do). It's not clear what the specific problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You could either print the result from each *menuOption* method

```
public static double menuOption2() {
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of kilometers you wish to convert: ");
    double km = keyBd.nextDouble();
    double miles = 0.621371 *km;
    System.out.println(String.format("%s", miles));
    return miles;
}
```

or from the case statements

```
switch(selection) {
    case '1': 
        double result = menuOption1(); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%s", result));
        break;
    case '2': 
        double result = menuOption2(); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%s", result));
        break;
    case '3': break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print result inside de Switch like this, also i added a new line, that request a argument.

```
 switch(selection) {
                case '1': {
                    System.out.println("Fill Kgs to be converted");
                    System.out.println("Result of converting KG to Lbs is : " + menuOption1());
                    break;
                }
                case '2': {
                    System.out.println("Fill Kilometers to be converted");
                    System.out.println("Result of converting Kms to Miles is : " + menuOption2());
                    break;
                }
                case '3': break;
                default: System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
            }//end switch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         case '1': System.out.println("Result "+menuOption1()); break;
         case '2': System.out.println("Result "+menuOption2()); break;
         case '3': break;
         default: System.out.println("Invalid selection!");
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21248739)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the assignment well, it requires you to create a class *MetricConverter* with 2 static methods in it, and a separate class *MetricConverterTest* with a main method. This would imply that you need to create a package for your classes.

With regards to displaying the result, within your main method you are only calling the methods which return type double, but you don't store or display their result in any way. You need to use `System.out.println( menuOptionX() );`, or assign the output of your method to a variable like this `Double result = menuOptionX();` and display it whenever you please with the aforementioned method.